# can terms lookup mechanism query by other field but id?

Tags: elasticsearch

here is elasticsearch official website about terms:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-terms-query.html

As we can see, if we want to do terms lookup mechanism query, we should use command like this:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/tweets/_search -d '{
  "query" : {
    "terms" : {
      "user" : {
        "index" : "users",
        "type" : "user",
        "id" : "2",
        "path" : "followers"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

But what if i want to do query by other field of users.
Assume that users has some other fields such as name and can i use terms lookup mechanism finding the tweets by giving users name but not id. 
I have tried to use command like this:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/tweets/_search -d '{
  "query" : {
    "terms" : {
      "user" : {
        "index" : "users",
        "type" : "user",
        "name" : "Jane",
        "path" : "followers"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

but it occurs error. 
Looking forward to your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The terms lookup mechanism is basically a built-in optimization to not have to make two queries to JOIN two indices, i.e. one in index A to get the ids to lookup and a second to fetch the documents with those ids in index B.

In contrary to SQL, such a JOIN can only work on the `id` field since this is the only way to uniquely retrieve a document from Elasticsearch via a GET call, which is exactly what Elasticsearch will do in the `terms` lookup.

So to answer your question, the terms lookup mechanism will not work on any other field than the `id` field since the first document to be retrieved must be unique. In your case, ES would not know how to fetch the document for the user with `name` `Jane` since `name` is just a field present in the user document, but in no way a unique identifier for user `Jane`.

Comment: Thanks! And do you know some methods instead? (What i can think out is to do 2 steps, the first to get ids of users whose name match Jane, and the second to do several of terms lookup queries for each id. That‘s efficiency is too low, is that?)

Comment: If you know you'll have a single `Jane` user (or just a few) then you can do it like suggested, but if there are 1000 Janes, then it won't be optimal, for sure. It seems like you want to search by username instead of by id. In that case, looking up the id of the user with username Jane and then doing the terms lookup won't be inefficient.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for anwser, I'll try the way you suggested, and look for some methods if possible.

Answer (score 5):

I think you did not understand exactly how this works. Terms lookup query works by reading values from a field of a document with the given id. In this case, you are trying to match the value of field `user` in `tweets` index with values of field `followers` in document with id `"2"` present in `users` index and `user` type.

If you want to read from any other field then simply mention that in `"path"`.

What you mainly need to understand is that the lookup values are all fetched from a field of a **single document** and not multiple documents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually i just learn to use ES recently. So there are too many details i don't know. But according to my question, you can see i have this requirement to do search like that, do you know some methods instead?  (What i can think out is to do 2 steps, the first to get ids of users whose name match Jane, and the second to do several of terms lookup queries for each id. That‘s efficiency is too low, is that?)